# Mathamatically deduce angle of vector for two values of Tangent

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

I have a rather simple requirement. I wish to find the angle of resultant vector with respect to x-axis, which I assume to be zero degrees. The problem I am facing is that, I want my mathematical formula to provide me the correct angle from the two values of inverse tangent. The method I am using are as follows:

Assuming two vectors A and B, which are at α and β from x-axis.

1. Resolve A and B to Ax, Ay, Bx, and By.
   $$Ax=A\cos \alpha, Ay=\sin \alpha$$ Similarly for Bx and By.
2. Resolve to find resultant:
   $$Rx=Ax+Bx, Ry=Ay+By$$ and
   $$R=\sqrt(Rx^2+Ry^2)$$
3. Resolve the angle
   $$\gamma  = \arctan ((Ay+By)/(Ax+Bx))$$
   Here in lies my problem. Assuming $$A=200,B=100,\alpha = 45, \beta=225$$
   I get two values for arctan 45 & 225.

I want a mathematical formula that will automatically produce the correct number in this case 225. The above approach works correctly if angles are less than 180 but not otherwise.

Comment: Use the signs of the numerator and denominator to disambiguate. If you’re coding this, look for a version of the arctangent function (typically named `ATAN2`) that takes two arguments instead of one.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I got what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The atan2(y,x) function is an enhanced version of arctangent which does exactly what you desire. You may familiarize yourself with the piecewise definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2?wprov=sfla1).